# Nokia Asha SDK files

Tags: linux, netbeans, java-me, nokia, nokia-s40

This is a very unusual request but since M$ took down the Nokia wiki pages, I can't seem to find some two files am looking for, namely

```
[http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/File:Emulator_preverify.zip][1]
[http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/File:FTEmulator_preverify.zip][2]
```

I'd deeply appreciate it if someone would share their copy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trawling on the internet, I came across an archive of the (now retired) Nokia Developer wiki where the above pages linked to.

https://archive.org/details/wiki-developernokiacom_community_wiki

Downloaded all the files and went through the extracted archives upon which I **DID** find both files. I've linked them below for anybody in future who may need them

[Emulator preverify.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByATRaa0CQhRZFNEcEIwSmFyNk0/view?usp=sharing)

[FTEmulator preverify.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByATRaa0CQhRV1QtdTRTdU1KZ1E/view?usp=sharing)